# ElasticSearch - How to return the input terms criteria in the output result

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do a search within elasticsearch using the regexp filters. Following is my query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "_source":["CODE"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [ 
                {
                   "regexp" : {
                      "CODE" : {
                        "value" : "[0]?[0]?[0]?[0]?3410086456[0-9]?",
                        "flags_value" : 0,
                        "boost" : 20.0
                      }
                    }
                },
                {
                   "regexp" : {
                      "CODE" : {
                        "value" : "[0]?[0]?[0]?[0]?83560900204[0-9]?",
                        "flags_value" : 0,
                        "boost" : 20.0
                      }
                    }
                }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
            "terms": {
                "CODETYPE": [
                     "TYPE1", "TYPE2", "TYPE3"
                ]
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the result of the query:

```
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 20.091797,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "index1",
                "_type": "type1",
                "_id": "142242",
                "_score": 20.091797,
                "_source": {
                    "CODE": "003410086456"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "index1",
                "_type": "type1",
                "_id": "375897",
                "_score": 20.091797,
                "_source": {
                    "CODE": "083560900204"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I need to get additionally in my output is the input term against which each result has matched. Something like this:

```
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 20.091797,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "index1",
                "_type": "type1",
                "_id": "142242",
                "_score": 20.091797,
                "_source": {
                    "CODE": "003410086456",
                    "INPUT": "3410086456"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "index1",
                "_type": "type1",
                "_id": "375897",
                "_score": 20.091797,
                "_source": {
                    "CODE": "083560900204",
                    "INPUT": "83560900204"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice the additional **INPUT** field above. That way I can map what pattern has mapped to which result. Is there any possibility in elasticsearch I can do this? I am currently unable to find any way of achieving this.

Appreciate your help on this. Let me know if I need to furnish any more information.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out? Would really appreciate if you give me some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

you could use **highlighting**, though it won't in `_source`, it would create a separate field `highlight` which gives the field value.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "_source": [
    "CODE"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "regexp": {
                  "CODE": {
                    "value": "[0]?[0]?[0]?[0]?3410086456[0-9]?",
                    "flags_value": 0,
                    "boost": 20
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "regexp": {
                  "CODE": {
                    "value": "[0]?[0]?[0]?[0]?83560900204[0-9]?",
                    "flags_value": 0,
                    "boost": 20
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "CODETYPE": [
              "TYPE1",
              "TYPE2",
              "TYPE3"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "CODE": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#search-request-highlighting

Comment: With highlight, I am getting:

"highlight": {
                    "CODE": [
                        "<em>00835609002045</em>"
                    ]
                }

But I need to get the actual input criteria, something like:

"highlight": {
                    "CODE": [
                        "<em>83560900204</em>"
                    ]
                }

Can you please suggest?

Comment: What do you want?
a.  `INPUT` to not contain leading 0's  (or)
b.  field value which was matched against the regex

Comment: I want the actual INPUT to reflect in the output json w.r.t to each of the matches. For e.g. for the first output block, I need to get 83560900204 in the output(not the results, but additionally as a different block) instead of 00835609002045. In this case, 83560900204 is the actual input  against which I have put the regex pattern. I need the input in the output json for traceability. Can you please help?